# Does posting my work to other sites jeapodize my site's traffic?

Tags: seo, search-engines, ranking

My website primarily showcases artwork that I make. But I also post my art to other pages (such as Instagram, Artstation) to try and get a bit more traction (forums too, but that's also for community engagement). I also sell products on my site, but then have most of these products on Etsy too. I'm often competing against myself for traffic.

All these other sites are better established and thus have better SEO, meaning their search rankings are higher than my own.

If I'm wanting to drive people to my site by finding my work in search engines, am I actually shooting myself in the foot by posting my art to other sites? Should I perhaps post to mine initially, wait some time, then post to the others? Is it reasonably possible to get my site above the others sites?

Answer (score 1):

Sites such as Instagram, Etsy and Facebook will always have better search rankings.  This is not just because they have been there for longer.  They are also more trusted.

As long as you the user reaches your artwork, you should regard it as job done (as long as you have a link there to your website).